# Openshift mysql connection error channel timeout

Tags: mysql, ssh, connection, openshift

I have an Tomcat 7 application on openshift and I have added a MySQL cartridge. I have a problem connecting to that database using MySQL workbench. 
I have added all the necessary parameters like hostname, username, password and SSH key, I have tested the connection and I get no errors. But when I try to connect to the db I get the following error:

> Your connection attempt failed for user 'adminxxxx' from your host to server xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3306:
>   Tunnel error: Remote connection to xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3306 failed: IOError('open SSH tunnel timeout',)

What can I do to fix this? Connecting to the db is a big part of the application.

Comment: Please, enum all fields that you have filled. They should be SSH USER, SSH HOSTNAME, SSH KEYFILE, MYSQL HOSTNAME, MYSQL SERVER PORT, USERNAME, PASSWORD.

Comment: I have filled all those fields correctly. I ended up adding a phpMyAdmin cartridge to gain access to the database. Still don't know what went wrong with MySQL Workbench.